# Apache Tomcat in OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, apache, tomcat, osx-yosemite

I'm using Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite and trying to run a NetBeans webapp using Apache Tomcat 8,
but whenever I try to startup the server I get the following output:

```
29-Oct-2014 00:40:31.158 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 8412 ms
```

And after some seconds "Failed starting up server" Message appears.

The server used to work well in OS X 10.9, any idea in what could be wrong?

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: it got solved changing the Java version to 1.8

Comment: Please post that as an Answer and accept it. Perfectly okay to answer your own Question on StackOverflow. Acceptance closes this question.

Comment: FYI, Yosemite ( Mac OS X 10.10 ) is still not certified for Java 8 Update 25. See [certification list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html). But I would guess that only Java 8 is being developed for Yosemite, and Java 7 will never be certified for Yosemite. Fortunately Java is extremely forward-compatible. You may well have no problems running on Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

it got solved changing the Java version to 1.8